# Redirect search query urls to new url structure

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, nsurlrequest

I have changed the platform of my site and therefore have a new search url structure.

The old url structure is like this:

/catalogsearch/result/?q=test

and the new url structure is like this:

/search_results.php?keyword=test&submit_search=

I have tried to redirect the old URLs to the new one using this code, but it doesnt appear to be working.

```
RewriteRule ^(catalogsearch\/result\/\?q=).*$ search_results.php?keyword=$1&submit_search= [L]
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}` to match query string.

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=([^&]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^catalogsearch/result/?$ search_results.php?keyword=%1&submit_search= [L]
```